# np.squeeze for assignments

Tags: python, numpy

I have `t.shape=(M, N)` and now I would like to assign new values `v` to a part of the array, which is indexed with variables `m` and `n`. `m` is an array and `n` either `int` or an array as well. 
I do `m=m.reshape(-1, 1)` in case `n` is an array. This works well for access like

```
t[m, n]
```

I can then use

```
np.squeeze(t[m, n])
```

to remove the additional dimension that was added before (if `n` is `int`).

However, if I do

```
t[m, n] = v
```

it won't work because if `n` is `int`, `v.shape=(m.size,)`, i.e. `v` has only a single dimension. I could check if `n` is an integer and change logic accordingly (either not adding a dimension to `m` or adding one to `v` as well).

Is there a more elegant solution to this (`np.squeeze(t[m, n]) = v` would be nice but obviously that's not how it works)?

**Edit:**

Concrete example:

```
def change_data(data, slices, channels, values):
    data[slices.reshape(-1, 1), channels] = values

data = np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(10, 4))
slices = np.arange(4)
channels = [2]
values = np.squeeze(np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(slices.size, len(channels)))) # The values come as a list
try:
    change_data(data, slices, channels, values) # Does not work
    print("Single channel does work")
except:
    print("Single channel does not work")
channels = [1, 2]
values = np.squeeze(np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(slices.size, len(channels))))
try:
    change_data(data, slices, channels, values) # Works
    print("Multi channel does work")
except:
    print("Multi channel does not work")
```

It looks a bit ridiculous in this simple example as I have an extra `np.squeeze` operation here, but depending on how many dimensions the array has, this can be a bit cumbersome, hence if I could just "squeeze" the index selection, the problem would be solved. I hope it is clearer now...

Comment: Give some concrete examples.  It's hard to picture what you are doing otherwise.  While I probably could construct some examples myself, I'd rather you did the work.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks for taking the time. I added a concrete example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [44]: data = np.arange(40).reshape(10,4)
```

By making the first index (4,1) shape, we can index with various sized second arrays:

```
In [46]: data[np.arange(4)[:,None],[2]]                                                   
Out[46]: 
array([[ 2],
       [ 6],
       [10],
       [14]])
In [47]: data[np.arange(4)[:,None],[1,2]]                                                 
Out[47]: 
array([[ 1,  2],
       [ 5,  6],
       [ 9, 10],
       [13, 14]])
```

The first result is (4,1) shape, the second (4,2).

With the `squeeze` we get (4,), the equivalent of indexing:

```
In [48]: data[np.arange(4),2]                                                             
Out[48]: array([ 2,  6, 10, 14])
```

`np.ix_` generates similar sets of indices, e.g. (4,1) and (1,2)

```
In [49]: np.ix_(np.arange(4),[1,2])                                                       
Out[49]: 
(array([[0],
        [1],
        [2],
        [3]]), array([[1, 2]]))
```

and (4,1) with (1,1):

```
In [50]: np.ix_(np.arange(4),[2])                                                         
Out[50]: 
(array([[0],
        [1],
        [2],
        [3]]), array([[2]]))
```

(m,1) broadcasts with a (1,n) to produce a (m,n) result.  (n,) works just as well as (1,n) - again the broadcasting rules.

With change you want to assign a value to that (m,n) block.  In this case a (4,2) works, as does a (4,1).  But you'd like to assign a (4,).  But by broadcasting the (4,) can broadcast to (1,4), but not to (4,1).  It can add a leading dimension, but not a trailing one.

```
In [51]: data[np.arange(4)[:,None],[2]]=np.ones(4)                                        
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-9245de6331ce> in <module>
----> 1 data[np.arange(4)[:,None],[2]]=np.ones(4)

ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (4,) could not be 
    broadcast to indexing result of shape (4,1)
In [52]: data[np.arange(4)[:,None],[2]] = np.ones((4,1))    # (4,1) into (4,1)
# (4,1) also goes into a (4,2)
In [53]: data[np.arange(4),[2]] = np.ones(4)   # (4,) into (4,)
In [55]: data[np.arange(4)[:,None],[1,2]] = np.zeros(2)  # (2,) into (4,2)
```

`flat` can be used to assign values in a 1d manner, but it doesn't work here because  `data[np.arange(4)[:,None],[1,2]]` is a copy if it is used in any way except directly in the `__setitem__` case, `data[...] = ...`.

Comment: This adds a lot of clarity to the issue, I especially didn't know about np.ix_ and the __setitem__ restriction mentioned in the last paragraph, thanks a lot for your explanations!